# Unable to update string value to null in target database during Copy Data Activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

**Source: Xml API(Json Format) Target: sql server**

```
[{
"captain":{
"row":[
{
"@name": "carlo",
"@runs":50.0,
"@mom": null,(target -double)
"@mos": nan(target-double)
},
{
"@name": "David ",
"@runs":500.0,
"@mom":5,
"@mos":1
}
]
}
}
]
```

My target database, sql server will only accepts double values. Whenever string value get passed it should update as null in target. Otherwise it will produce error. What should I do here for solving my issue. I got one solution.

In the source dataset of xml api, there is a field called Null Value. There we can mention which string should i update as null in target. But the issue is if one string(null) comes in source ,it will updates an null in target .But at the same time another string comes(nan) ,I am not able to update AS NULL in target database. What should I do here?

**Pls note: I cannot use dataflows since our organisation not using azure ir.**

Comment: Do the `null and nan` come as strings from your xml api output?

Comment: @Saideep Arikontham Yes  both comes as string  in the xml api o/ps

Comment: Can you please confirm whether the given is the exact format of the response (say number of rows) or is it just a sample and there can be many other rows?

Comment: @Saideep Arikontham  That depends on the api response. But the number of rows will be static(for evry api reponse,the return number of rows will be unique,it will not change). But here i gave a sample data

Comment: @Saideep Arikontham Any idea?

Comment: Trying an approach using ADF only, will update as soon as I get a solution

Comment: @Saideep Arikontham Sure Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have access to azure blob storage?

Comment: @SaideepArikontham Ofcourse Yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248188/discussion-between-being-real-and-saideep-arikontham).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First copy the XML API response to a csv file with null value as `null`.
Now, in this CSV file, the columns (double type), have `null and nan` values. One thing we can do is convert all the `nan` records to `null` records. Then read the final CSV file which only contains null values (by specifying source dataset nul value as `null` and sink as sql table).

Please look at the following demonstration.

- Lets say I have data as shown below after writing the XML API response to CSV (demo column is float in target table. My target table has the name as `tp` so I mapped it properly).

[image]

- Now, we need to convert all the `nan` values to null. So, create a copy data activity where source is the above csv file and sink in a new csv file (or the same file but in different datasets, one for source and one for sink. Then above csv will be overwritten). I used the same CSV file as my source and sink.
- The following is the source dataset configuration where my file path is `data/MyFolder/sample1.csv` and my null value is `nan`

[image]

- The following is the sink dataset configuration where my file path is `data/MyFolder/sample1.csv` and my null value is `null`. This converts all `nan` to `null`.

[image]

- The copy data succeeds and creates the following output:

[image]

- Now, Create a new copy activity where source dataset file would be the above csv file with null value as `null`. You can see the values are read as null in the below image.

[image]

- Use sink as your SQL table and run the pipeline.
  [image]
- The activity would run successfully and insert the values properly. The output of my target table when I use the following query:

```
select * from demo2
```

[image]

- The output when I select rows where tp is null:

```
select  *  from demo2 where tp is  null
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you But I cannot use this option since my source api sometimes contains more than 100 columns as input

Comment: Achieving this in ADF would be difficult considering API outputs varying columns. Is it possible for you to cast the double column to a string, update with null on columns where a valid double value does not exist, and then cast it back to double once all the invalid values are replaced with null.

Comment: it is not varying columns columns are fixed only ,(may be some api return 100 columns) That need to check,Also can u please   tell what is the function of  null value field in source api dataset ?

Comment: What number of values do you want to specify as null value for the source api dataset? ()

Comment: 2 columns only facing the issue

Comment: I mean, in the sample, both `null` and `nan` strings should be considered as NULL values right? how many such values are there?

Comment: only  2 values  are there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248199/discussion-between-saideep-arikontham-and-being-real).